# startup script to check if external monitor is attached

Tags: python, hardware, detection

My first question here; normally I can find answers with a couple searches, but not this time.

I want to write a script that will run on start up to check if an external monitor is attached to a laptop.

I would like write the script in python.

I'm using 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04. I've searched around but can't really find anything useful. Any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but including information about the platform you're on might be useful to others.

Comment: Oh yeah that would be useful. I'm using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Do you want the script to run as part of the system boot process or as part of the login process to a desktop session (probably GNOME in your case)? Knowing  your use case could also help in providing a correct answer.

Comment: I want it to run in the GNOME desktop. After detecting if a second monitor is attached I want to setup nvidia to use the second monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `xrandr` should do the trick:

```
$ xrandr -q
...
VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+0+26 ...
   ...
LVDS connected 1400x1050+1280+0 ...
   ...
DVI-0 disconnected ...
```

Inside your python script, run this command using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, then search the output string for the screen identifier you're looking for, e.g. "VGA-0 connected".

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to accept/upvote the answer -- not only because this gives me some rep points but also because it clearly indicates that this answer is a good one for your question (helpful for other people coming around).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I upvoted your question, i.e. your rep is on its way to 15 ;)